# Ruby's grpc(v1.3.2) gem SSL/TLS connection issue with grpc server built entirely in golang

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, go, grpc

Recently, I was trying to use rubygem grpc version 1.3.2 as a clinet and connect to a grpc server which is built from golang. I went through the documentation at [GRPC.IO](http://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth.html) and used it in my code as it.

```
    irb(main):017:0> GRPC::Core::Credentials.new(File.read(CA_FILE_PATH))
NameError: uninitialized constant GRPC::Core::Credentials
        from (irb):17
        from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
        from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
        from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

However their documentation specifically says,

```
creds = GRPC::Core::Credentials.new(load_certs)  # load_certs typically loads a CA roots file
stub = Helloworld::Greeter::Stub.new('myservice.example.com', creds)
```

Then I came across **ChannelCredentials** and the *creds* is supposed to be either **ChannelCredentials** object or a symbol(e.g. *:this_channel_is_insecure*). Hence, I gave it a try as well.

I've taken the following function from the grpc gem's source code itself. This function was called in rspec test cases for loading the certs:

```
def load_certs
      data_dir = "#{Rails.root}/certs"
      files = ['ca.pem', 'server.key', 'server.pem']
      files.map { |f| File.open(File.join(data_dir, f)).read }
end
```

Then I gave it a try with,

```
channel_creds = GRPC::Core::ChannelCredentials.new(load_certs)
stub = Helloworld::Greeter::Stub.new('myservice.example.com', channel_creds)
```

But the above failed with

```
E0619 09:59:10.410575570   14208 ssl_transport_security.c:601] Could not load any root certificate.
E0619 09:59:10.410604954   14208 ssl_transport_security.c:1315] Cannot load server root certificates.
E0619 09:59:10.410622519   14208 security_connector.c:837]   Handshaker factory creation failed with TSI_INVALID_ARGUMENT.
```

I also tried:

```
channel_creds = GRPC::Core::ChannelCredentials.new(File.read(CA_FILE_PATH))
stub = Helloworld::Greeter::Stub.new('myservice.example.com', creds)
```

But all I got was error from the logs or rpc server:

```
2017/06/16 10:52:34 transport: http2Server.HandleStreams failed to receive the preface from client: EOF
2017/06/16 10:53:35 transport: http2Server.HandleStreams failed to receive the preface from client: EOF
2017/06/16 10:53:59 transport: http2Server.HandleStreams failed to receive the preface from client: EOF
2017/06/16 10:55:06 transport: http2Server.HandleStreams failed to receive the preface from client: EOF
```

Has anyone successfully tried this Ruby client Golang server combination with SSL/TLS enabled?

Answer (score 4):

> creds is supposed to be either ChannelCredentials object or a symbol

Yes the second argument of a client stub constructor (the creds argument), should be either a `GRPC::Core::ChannelCredentials` object or *specifically* the `::this_channel_is_insecure` symbol (if the latter is passed, an insecure connection will be used).

I'd note that the test that uses

```
def load_certs
  data_dir = "#{Rails.root}/certs"
  files = ['ca.pem', 'server.key', 'server.pem']
  files.map { |f| File.open(File.join(data_dir, f)).read }
end
```

might actually be misleading, since it only makes sense to construct channel credentials with the *client's* private key and certificate chain (that specific test I believe doesn't use the key and cert chain).

**On the `GRPC::Core::ChannelCredentials` constructor:**

There are three forms that can be used, (there's a comment above the constructor code in https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/ruby/ext/grpc/rb_channel_credentials.c#L128 that goes over them), but the options are:

- `Credentials.new()`
- `Credentials.new(pem_root_certs)`
- `Credentials.new(pem_root_certs, pem_private_key, pem_cert_chain)`

In all cases, the roots file, private key, and cert chain parameters are pem encoded strings.

Note that if no arguments are passed (`Credentials.new()` is used), then the server root certificates will be found as described in [this header comment](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/include/grpc/grpc_security.h#L147) (see the description for the behavior when server root certs parameter is null). And the last constructor is only needed if you want the *client* to use a private key and cert chain.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this works.

```
channel_creds = GRPC::Core::ChannelCredentials.new(File.read("/home/user/.lnd/tls.cert"))
stub = Lnrpc::Lightning::Stub.new("127.0.0.1:10009", channel_creds)
obj = Lnrpc::GetInfoRequest.new
pp stub.get_info(obj)
```